# multidimensional array to one dimensional array recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, flatten

I have this multidimensional array

```
$liste = [[1,2,3],5,[['x','y','z'],true]];
```

and I want to change it to one dimensionel array

```
$liste = [1,2,3,5,'x','y','z',true];
```

so i always have a problem that give me the same shape

```
function to_array($list){
    $out=[];
    if(!is_array($list)){
        return $list;
    }else{
        foreach($list as $line){
            $out[]= to_array($line);
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

where is the problem in this recursive function !!!

Comment: Related: [How to flatten a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/2711071).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are pushing the result of `to_array` into `$out`, when what you want to do is use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). Now since that requires both parameters to be arrays, when `$list` is not an array, you need to return an array containing the individual value. So change these lines:

```
    return $list;
        $out[]= to_array($line);
```

To:

```
    return array($list);
        $out = array_merge(to_array($line));
```

i.e.

```
function to_array($list){
    $out=[];
    if(!is_array($list)){
        return array($list);
    }else{
        foreach($list as $line){
            $out = array_merge($out, to_array($line));
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

And you will get the result that you want:

```
var_export(to_array($liste));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 5,
  4 => 'x',
  5 => 'y',
  6 => 'z',
  7 => true,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_walk_recursive()` delivers the desired result from an array of indeterminate depth in a one-liner because it only visits the "leaf-nodes" -- effectively, you don't need to bother checking if an element is or is not an array.

`array_walk_recursive()` doesn't return an array, it returns `true`|`false` based on whether or not there was a failure.

`&$flat` is a variable which is "passed by reference".  This means that `$flat` can act as a vehicle to transport the data from inside the function scope to outside the function scope.  As the elements are traversed, each new value is pushed into `$flat` using square bracket syntax.

This is exactly what this function does best -- use it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5vreA))

```
$liste = [[1, 2, 3], 5, [['x', 'y', 'z'], true]];
array_walk_recursive($liste, function($v) use (&$flat){ $flat[] = $v; });
var_export($flat);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 5,
  4 => 'x',
  5 => 'y',
  6 => 'z',
  7 => true,
)
```